# Azure Search with Azure SQL View Issue

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

First I created View in Azure SQL:

```
SELECT
    [P].[Id]
FROM [dbo].[table1] [P]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tabl2] [PL] ON [P].[Id] = [PL].[Id]
```

**Total Count is 1000 rows.**

Then I created Azure Search Datasource

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://....search.windows.net/$metadata#datasources/$entity",
    "name": "ds",
    "description": "",
    "type": "azuresql",
    "subtype": null,
    "credentials": {
        "connectionString": "..."
    },
    "container": {
        "name": "view_test",
        "query": null
    },
    "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",
        "highWaterMarkColumnName": "Id"
    },
    "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy": null
}
```

Then Azure Search Index

```
{
    "@odata.context": "....search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
    "name": "testing-index",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "Id",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": true,
            "analyzer": null
        }
    ],
    "scoringProfiles": [],
    "defaultScoringProfile": "",
    "corsOptions": null
}
```

Then Indexer

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://....search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "name": "indexer-test",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "ds",
  "targetIndexName": "testing-index",
  "schedule": {
    "interval": "PT05M",
    "startTime": "2016-12-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "parameters": {
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": false
  }
}
```

**When I checked Azure Portal and looked at the Indexer I see Documents succeeded 1000. But the index DOCUMENT COUNT contain only the total count for Azure SQL table1**

So I tried to run the following

```
https://....search.windows.net/indexes/testing-index/docs/$count?api-version=2016-09-01
```

I have waited a day for the index to get update with no luck. I followed the same steps and use Table instead of View , it worked as charm.

The issue got resolved. The Id shouldn't be the key.